# What does "Botox in real life" mean here?

Tags: meaning, literature

I would like to know what "Botox in real life" means in the following sentences:

> ‘Now,’ Will says, palm on my back as a gentle steer, warm through my
> dress, ‘let me introduce you to some people. This is Georgina.’
>
> Georgina, thin and chic in a column of fuchsia silk, gives me a wintry
> smile. She can’t move her face much and I try hard not to stare – I’m
> not sure I’ve ever seen **Botox in real life**. ‘Were you on the hen
> do?’ she asks. ‘I can’t remember.’
>
> ‘I had to give it a miss,’ I say. ‘The kids . . .’ Partly true. But
> there’s also the fact that it was on a yoga retreat in Ibiza and I
> could never in a million years have afforded it.

- Lucy Foley, *The Guest List*, Chapter 12

This is a thriller novel published in 2020 in the United Kingdom. One hundred and fifty guests would be gathering at some remote and deserted fictional islet called Inis an Amplóra off the coast of the island of Ireland to celebrate the wedding between Jules (a self-made woman running an online magazine called *The Download*) and Will (a celebrity appearing in a TV show program called *Survive the Night*). The day before the actual wedding day, Hannah, the wife of Charlie (Jules' friend), arrived at the island and is now at the dinner party for the rehearsal dinner with only some selected guests. And during the party, Hannah meets Georgina, who was like "Botox in real life."

In this part, I am wondering what "Botox in real life" would mean. Does that mean Hannah has never seen someone who used Botox in her daily lives? Or would its meaning be closer to that Georgina was like the incarnation of Botox, like her entire face was injected with Botox...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'In real life' means 'in the real world and not in a story'. The speaker says that Georgina 'can't move her face much'. Although Hannah may have read about Botox and seen pictures of its effects, she has never before met and seen someone who has had Botox treatment.

Comment: I have to say I have met someone who had Botox, and I shudder still when I think about it.